# Ajax.beginform in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using ASP.NET Razor and there is Ajax.BeginForm which post form without full page refresh. Moreover, it has all the Ajax Options like Confirm, OnSuccess, OnFailure, OnComplete, OnBegin etc : here are the full details: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Do we have any inbuilt class equivalant to Ajax.beginform that could be used in Laravel Blade?

Answer (score 0):

There's something similar. But you'll have to do the ajax calls yourself. You have to add `illuminate/html` to your packages:

```
composer require illuminate/html
```

…and then register it in `/config/app.php`:

```
// ...

'providers' => [
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],

// ...

'aliases' => [
    'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
],
```

…and then you can create a form with blade:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
<!-- your fields -->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

…and hack your form so it sends it using Ajax through jQuery :

```
var form = $('form')
.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Sent.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to write the jquery code. That's what ASP.NET MVC Razor is doing.

Comment: After having checked, i'm afraid there's currently no package for Laravel that's able to do that. The above javacript snippet will do the trick for any `<form>` element.